# Maven - changing deployed artifact name

Tags: maven, tomcat, liferay, liferay-theme

when i deploy an artifact (**Liferay Portal theme**) to **Tomcat**, it is stored in directory `webapps/artifactId-version/`. However, I do need for directory to be named without the version suffix. How can I accomplish that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`recommended-deployment-context`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/definitions/liferay-plugin-package_7_0_0.dtd#L45) configuration. That will make Liferay's deployer rename your artifact before deploying it into Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You don't describe how you deploy, but I assume that this should do the trick: http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Build change the project.build.finalName to

```
<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
```

Comment: That only changes the name of .war file, I need to change the name that can be seen after deployment to portal/server, which creates a new dir.

Comment: In that case it's not a Maven issue. I would expect that the name of the war-file is used for the folder in the webapps

Comment: Thanks for pushing me in the right direction! I've managed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it was Liferay Portal specific issue. What worked for me was adding `liferay-plugin-package.properties` file. Although there isn't anything close to name-like info in it (maybe it is because of `<module-incremental-version>`), if this file is present, it names the deployed folder without the version suffix.